# Autocomplete for curly brackets and quotes not working in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently downloaded VS on my new computer, but I've been running into a strange issue. Parentheses and straight brackets will autocomplete just fine, but for some reason, curly brackets and quotation marks won't and I'll have to type in the second one manually. This is really disruptive and goes against my workflow, so does anyone know how I can fix this? I'm getting this issue with both .NET applications and scripts using the Unity Syntax.